# UWP, my app crashes for the image path when built , but when I run it on the debugger it works fine

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm creating a UWP  that receives the image path from a static class. It works fine when I'm debugging it, but when built, the application crashes.

I have tried with a lot of different ways of accessing the image path from code behind (Uri, BitmapImage, etc.) which has been defined by the selected object. Below, you can see the code that has allowed me to do it. The try and catch was a way for me to notice if that was what had been crashing the application.

```
try
{
      ImageSource result = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///" + 
      EntriesDone.SelectedEntry.ImagePath));

                img_entry.Source = result;
                img_entry.Opacity = 0.40;
                img_entry.MaxWidth = 500;
                img_entry.MaxHeight = 500;
            }
catch (Exception)
{
     txt_Name.FontSize=2;
}
```

What I would like to know is if there is a better way for me to access the image path or the assets folder allowing the object to define the image that will be shown (there are more than 60 entries so I need to do it efficiently) and that won't crash the application upon being built. I'd also like to know why this crashes the application when built. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, Can you give me some more information? For example, the full link to the picture. I suspect that the crash of the application may be caused by the inability of the image link to be accessed, so it would be helpful if you could provide a full image link.

Comment: Hello, it is a relative path: "Assets\image.png"

Comment: I see. so the combined path is `ms-appx:///Assets\image.png`? The separators here are not consistent. In addition to this, you mentioned in the question, you want to show more than 60 pictures, do I need to provide some advice on data binding? It can avoid you setting the path manually.

Comment: Oh, that explains a lot! I'll read about data binding (I'm still learning lol), thanks for the advice!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

> What I would like to know is if there is a better way for me to access the image path or the assets folder allowing the object to define the image that will be shown

For your requirement, you can use `DataTemplate` and `ListView` (or `GridView`) to show the images.

1. create data model:

```cs
public class ImageModel
{
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    // Other properties
    ...
}
```

2. In the code-behind file of the page, create a new collection and fill the data:

```cs
// ObservableCollection can notify UI when collection item changed
public ObservableCollection<ImageModel> ImageCollection = new ObservableCollection<ImageModel>();

public TestImagePage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    ImageInit();
}

public void ImageInit()
{
    // Load image model here.
    // e.g.
    ImageCollection.Add(new ImageModel{ImageUrl="ms-appx:///Assets/image.png"});
}
```

3. Create DataTemplate and GridView on XAML:

```xml
<Page
    ...>
    <Grid>
        <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ImageCollection}">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ImageModel">
                    <Image Opacity="0.4"
                       MaxWidth="500"
                       MaxHeight="500"
                       Source="{x:Bind ImageUrl}"
                       />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The process I provide is very simple, you can expand this code according to your needs.

Best regards.